# The program can not initialize because SDL2_mixer.dll is missing in the computer

Tags: c++, dll

This only happens when I open a specific code in a project. Any other project on my computer using SDL2_mixer.dll is working just fine.

I've tried to put the .dll in the system file, but then this error code appears "0xc000007b".

I've tried to reinstall VS (I'm using 2017 version) and nothing.

I would really appreciate some help in this matter.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you install SDL?

Comment: Maybe you are mixing 32 and 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try put dll in folder with executable file.
2. Try to build that library for your machine -
   https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/
3. Try bit another version of library.
4. Check library decencies. Possibly you not have 3rd party
   libraries required for that library.